# How can I get my hyperlink in HTML result in same page or window with or without using iframe tag or JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Here are two html files and one css file. My question is how to open link monday.html on the same page or window in my  section. i.e. when one click on mondy navigation button one get the result in content where lorem ipsum is shown.

/this is index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Navigation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
        <h1>Welcome to My page</h1>

        <div id="content">
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis a felis. Sed ac mauris eget 
            eros vestibulum luctus. Phasellus ultrices consequat arcu. Aliquam rhoncus, elit nec faucibus
            scelerisque, nisi ligula imperdiet dui, in lacinia nulla odio sit amet lorem. Praesent tristique, 
            orci ac posuere rhoncus, massa urna semper purus, et tempus justo massa a massa. Cras nec turpis
            non massa lacinia facilisis. Phasellus gravida nisl eget metus. Fusce gravida, dui ac accumsan
            sagittis, nisl quam interdum tortor, sed gravida risus lectus eget dui. Aliquam vitae justo ac 
            risus gravida convallis. Nulla quis diam a mi aliquam tempor. Duis dignissim erat vitae nisl. 
            Fusce vel lorem. Duis neque dolor, tempor nec, cursus id, convallis in, enim. Morbi egestas 
            lobortis neque.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <h2>Weekdays</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a  href="monday.html">Monday</a></li>
                <li>Tuesday</li>
                <li>Wednesday</li>
                <li>Thursday</li>
                <li>Friday</li>
                <li>Saturday</li>
                <li>Sunday</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Copyright &copy; MyPage</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



my css code is as follows:-
/*
Mypage css file
*/

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #cfcdb4;
    border-top: 10px solid #bcba9e;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #6d8ead;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    background: #362416;
    border-left: 5px solid #281a0f;
    border-right: 5px solid #281a0f;
}

#wrap h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #553f2d;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #362416;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}


#content {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}

#content h2 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 260px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

#sidebar ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#sidebar h2 {
    background: #553f2d;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

#footer {
    padding: 10px;
    clear: both;
    font-size: small;
}

#footer p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #281a0f;
    text-align: center;
}



the hyperlink monday.html is as follows:-


<html>
    <head>
    <title>Monday</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    This is a monday page
    </body>
 <html>
```

Comment: Not possible without some javascripting. As to show or even hide elements, some javascripting has to be incorporated. If you have seen any such example somewhere where no script, etc. is used and it is pure CSS, link those here.

Comment: Thanks Lee but how can you make it with javascript. I would recommend if you execute the html and css code in editor .you probable missed my question ,i said with iframe tag of html, javascript or without both

Comment: Yes I got your question correctly and that is why I pointed to use javascripting as a way to achive it, as you want a pure CSS solution, but as far as I know, that is not possible, so some javascripting functions for onclick show elements and hide elements should be used to achieve this. Correct me if you thing I still misunderstood you question. - @Kai

Comment: Hey Lee could you please add some javacript codes in it so that I could get the results i wanted.

Comment: I have hinted you the solution. You need to research and try it and if you are stuck up, shall suggest resolve. Hope justified :) - @Kai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most basic way I can think of is this using jquery.

```
$('#sidebar a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var location = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(location);
});
```

However should most probably use a proper ajax or $.get function if you want more control

Answer (score -1):

You will use AJAX to achieve this. Heres an awesome article below:

http://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)